# Return the last element of an enum as Default in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a rust implementation as follows and in default implementation, for the enum, I need to return the last element and I need to achieve it without hardcoding it.

```
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
#[derive(Clone,  PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Region<CountryId> {
    None,
    Category(CountryId),
}

#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Litrature1<CountryId> {
    pub Seek: Region<CountryId>,
    pub Write: Region<CountryId>,
}

#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Litrature2<CountryId> {
    pub Seek: Region<CountryId>,
    pub Write: Region<CountryId>,
    pub Work: Region<CountryId>,
}

#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug))]
#[derive(Clone,  PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Alphabets<CountryId> {
    A1(Litrature1<CountryId>),
    A2(Litrature1<CountryId>)
}


impl<CountryId> Default for Alphabets<CountryId> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        // How to return the last element of the enum as default?
        Alphabets<CountryId>::A2
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a723decb142119f88ebbce72bf9297b)

I am uncertain how to make this work

Comment: Your `Alphabets` enum variants each wrap around a `LitratureX` value, so what should the value of that be for your default implementation? Should it be a Literature1 with `Region::None` for `Seek` and `Write`?

Comment: Yes , thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you essentially want default values all the way down, where each region defaults to `Region::None`. In that context, it would make the most sense to define `Default` on each nested type, e.g.

Default for `Region`

```
impl<CountryId> Default for Region<CountryId> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Region::None
    }
}
```

Default for `Litrature1`

```
impl<CountryId> Default for Litrature1<CountryId> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Litrature1 {
            Seek: Default::default(),
            Write: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}
```

Default for `Litrature2`

```
impl<CountryId> Default for Litrature2<CountryId> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Litrature2 {
            Seek: Default::default(),
            Write: Default::default(),
            Work: Default::default(),
        }
    }
}
```

Default for `Alphabets`

```
impl<CountryId> Default for Alphabets<CountryId> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Alphabets::A2(Default::default())
    }
}
```

([On the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db4096d994bcb9cb4ffeca40937fedac))

Comment: Or you could just derive `Default`

Comment: @loganfsmyth
Rather than Hardcoding the last item as ::A2 Im  looking for a dynamic way to get the last item

Thanks

Comment: @mcarton Unfortunately that would require `CountryId` to implement `Default` because of https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925.

Comment: @co2f2e Would something like https://github.com/idanarye/rust-smart-default work? There's nothing special about the last variant of an enum, so it's it's not something that would be built in.